# Creating a rotate3D() function for PMatrix3D in Processing

Tags: matrix, processing, matrix-multiplication, rotational-matrices

Some time ago, I coded a little fidgetable logo based on CSS transforms alone.

You can fiddle with it over https://document.paris/

The result feels nice, it feels natural to click/touch and drag to rotate the logo.

I remember banging my head against the walls until I found out that I could chain CSS transforms quite easily just by chaining them.

```
transform: matrix3d(currentMatrix) rotate3d(x, y, z, angle);
```

And most importantly to get the currentMatrix I would simply do `m = $('#logobackground').css('transform');` with jQuery, the browser would magically return the computed matrix instead of the raw "css" which actually avoided me to deal with matrices or to infinitely stack rotate3D() properties.

So the hardest part was then to calculate the rotate3D arguments (x, y, z, angle) based on mouse inputs. In theory shouldn't have problems transposing this part to java so i'll just skip over it.

**Now**

I'm trying to do the exact same thing with Processing and there is two problems :

1. There is no rotate3D() in processing.
2. There is no browser to apply/chain transformations and return me the current matrix state automatically.

Here's the plan/implementation I'm working on :

I need a "currentMatrix" to apply every frame to the scene

```
PMatrix3D currentMatrix = new PMatrix3D();
```

In the `setup()` I set it to the "identity matrix" which from what I understand is equivalent to "no transformation".

```
// set currentMatrix to identity Matrix
currentMatrix.set(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Every frame I would calculate a transformation matrix and apply it to the currentMatrix.
Then I would apply this matrix to the scene.

```
// Apply Matrix to the currentMatrix
void mouseRotate() {
    float diag = sqrt(pow(width,2)+pow(height,2));
    float x = deltaX()/ diag * 10; // deltaX = difference between previous prevous MouseX and current mouseX)
    float y = deltaY()/ diag * 10; // deltaY = same with Y axis
    float angle = sqrt( pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) );
    currentMatrix.apply( rotate3D(y,x,0,angle) );
}
// Apply Matrix to the scene
applyMatrix(currentMatrix);
```

**PMatrix3D reference** : https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html

**ApplyMatrix() reference** : https://processing.org/reference/applyMatrix_.html

All I need to do then is to implement the rotate3D css transform as a function which returns a transformation matrix.

Based on what I found on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d()

[image: mozilla doc css rotate3D transform function description matrix]

I implemented this first function :

```
PMatrix3D rotate3D(float x, float y, float z, float a) {
    PMatrix3D rotationMatrix = new PMatrix3D();
    rotationMatrix.set(
        1+(1-cos(a))*(pow(x,2)-1),  z*sin(a)+x*y*(1-cos(a)),    -y*sin(a)+x*z*(1-cos(a)),   0,
        -z*sin(a)+x*y*(1-cos(a)),   1+(1-cos(a))*(pow(y,2)-1),  x*sin(a)+y*z*(1-cos(a)),    0,
        y*sin(a)+x*z*(1-cos(a)),    -x*sin(a)+y*z*(1-cos(a)),   1+(1-cos(a))*(pow(z,2)-1),  0,
        0,0,0,1
    );
    return rotationMatrix;
}
```

and based on what I found on this page https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#Rotate3dDefined
[image: draftcsswg css rotate 3D transform function description matrix]
I implemented this other function :

```
PMatrix3D rotate3Dbis(float getX, float getY, float getZ, float getA) {
    float sc = sin(getA/2)*cos(getA/2);
    float sq = pow(sin(getA/2),2);
    float normalizer = sqrt( pow(getX,2) + pow(getY,2) + pow(getZ,2) );
    float x = getX/normalizer;
    float y = getY/normalizer;
    float z = getZ/normalizer;

    PMatrix3D rotationMatrix = new PMatrix3D();
    rotationMatrix.set(
        1-2*(pow(y,2)+pow(z,2))*sq, 2*(x*y*sq-z*sc),            2*(x*z*sq+y*sc),            0,
        2*(x*y*sq+z*sc),            1-2*(pow(x,2)+pow(z,2))*sq, 2*(y*z*sq-x*sc),            0,
        2*(x*z*sq-y*sc),            2*(y*z*sq+x*sc),            1-2*(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)*sq), 0,
        0,                          0,                          0,                          1
    );
    return rotationMatrix;
}
```

When testing, they don't produce exactly the same result with the same inputs (although the differences are kind of "symmetric" which makes me think that they are kind of equivalent at least in some way ?) Also rotate3Dbis() has a tendency to produce NaN numbers, especially when i'm not moving the mouse (x & y = 0).

But most importantly, in the end it doesn't work. Instead of rotating, the drawing just zooms out progressively when I'm using `rotate3D()`, and `rotate3Dbis()` doesn't render correctly because of the NaNs.

**The overall question :**
I'm trying to get guidance from people who understand transformations Matrices and trying to narrow down where the issue is. Are my processing/java implementations of `rotate3D()` flawed ? Or would the issue come from somewhere else ? And are my `rotate3D()` and `rotate3Dbis` functions equivalent ?

[image: Processing println PMatrix3D Matrix Result]

Comment: after more testing, with `rotate3D()`there seem to actually be a rotation so it's at least partially working.

But there also seem to be a scaling and/or translation that randomly makes the shape progressively very small (until invisible) or very big (gigantic).

Could this be a problem of using double instead of float ? or and error in the function ?

Comment: I fixed this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839347/creating-a-rotate3d-function-for-pmatrix3d-in-processing/69843890#69843890
The short answer was I needed to normalize `x` `y` and `z` and avoid division by zero to avoid the `Nan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get away with simply rotating on X and Y axis, as you already mentioned, using the previous and current mouse coordinates:

```
PVector cameraRotation = new PVector(0, 0);

void setup(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  strokeWeight(9);
  strokeJoin(MITER);
}

void draw(){
  //update "camera" rotation
  if (mousePressed){
    cameraRotation.x += -float(mouseY-pmouseY);
    cameraRotation.y += float(mouseX-pmouseX);
  }
  
  background(255);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateX(radians(cameraRotation.x));
  rotateY(radians(cameraRotation.y));
  rect(0, 0, 300, 450);
}
```

The Document Paris example you've shared also uses easing. You can have a look at this [minimal easing Processing example](https://processing.org/examples/easing.html)

Here's a version of the above with easing applied:

```java
PVector cameraRotation = new PVector();
PVector cameraTargetRotation = new PVector();
float easing = 0.01;

void setup(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  strokeWeight(9);
  strokeJoin(MITER);
}

void draw(){
  //update "camera" rotation
  if (mousePressed){
    cameraTargetRotation.x += -float(mouseY-pmouseY);
    cameraTargetRotation.y +=  float(mouseX-pmouseX);
  }
  
  background(255);
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  // ease rotation
  rotateX(radians(cameraRotation.x -= (cameraRotation.x - cameraTargetRotation.x) * easing));
  rotateY(radians(cameraRotation.y -= (cameraRotation.y - cameraTargetRotation.y) * easing));
  fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, 300, 450);
  fill(0);
  translate(0, 0, 3);
  rect(0, 0, 300, 450);
}
```

Additionally there's a library called [PeasyCam](https://github.com/jdf/peasycam) which can make this much simpler.

If you do want to implement your own version using PMatrix3D here are a couple of tips that could save you time:

- When you instantiate `PMatrix3D()` it's the identity matrix. If you have transformations applied and you want to [`reset()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html#reset--) to identity.
- If you want to rotate a `PMatrix3D()` around and axis the [`rotate(float angleInRadians, float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ)`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html#rotate-float-float-float-float-) override should help.
- Additionally you could get away without `PMatrix3D` since `resetMatrix()` will reset the global transformation matrix and you can call `rotate(float angleInRadians, float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ)` directly.

Comment: Wow, there is some usefull information here !

Comment: The easing part I kind of wanted to get rid of it as this project is more of a tool than an "animation" so I didn't need anything fancy. 

I think the `rotate(float angleInRadians, float axisX, float axisY, float axisZ)` function you just shared is exactly the rotate3D() function I spend the whole day making yesterday (and the title of the question). So... that's nice haha.

Comment: I tested your script and basically it does exactly the same thing as my current code below (with the easing added and way less code to do the same thing !).
The problem is that the X and Y rotation are not relative to the "user" but to the "tablet/phone/rectangle".

I thought that using matrices and be able to "stack" (multiply) them would enable me to keep "the scene/camera" as a reference point instead of the content.

This morning I tried with a `camera()` with no luck yet !

I'll try peasyCam maybe they have something !

Comment: I confirm that switching my `PMatrix3D.apply(rotate3D(x,y,z,a)` with `PMatric3D.rotate(a,x,y,z)` makes no difference. So my day was well spend !

Comment: peasycam seems to be doing exactly what I'm aiming for : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lk0tEhxcIU

but the website seems to be down, the github is missing the build .jar and I can't seem to be able to import it from the P2 or p4 library manager. 
Do you have any copy of the library ?

Comment: @PierreRose Unfortunately I won't be available for more details for most of the day. Indeed my answer above is just another way to mimic/fake arcball rotation very similar to your answer. You can't replace experience: great you got the hang of PMatrix3D :) I've uploaded a copy [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/peasycam.zip). Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for the peasycam build. It fixed everything in around 5 minutes. And it's currently not available anywhere that I could look for

Comment: FWIW You can download PeaseCam here: https://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/

Comment: The website was down at the time ! But thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is a fix added to the first rotate3D function.
I needed to normalize the x,y,z values to avoid the weird scaling.

I'm posting the current state of the code (i'm skipping a few parts for the sake of simplicity):

```
// Mouse movement since last fame on X axis
float deltaX() {
    return (float)(mouseX-pmouseX);
}

// Mouse movement since last fame on Y axis
float deltaY() {
    return (float)(mouseY-pmouseY);
}

// Convert user input into angle and amount to rotate to
void mouseRotate() {
    double diag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
    double x = deltaX()/ diag * 50;
    double y = -deltaY()/ diag * 50;
    double angle = Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y );
    currentMatrix.apply( rotate3D((float)y,(float)x,0,(float)angle) );
}

// Convert those values into a rotation matrix
PMatrix3D rotate3D(float getX, float getY, float getZ, float getA) {
    float normalizer = sqrt( getX*getX + getY*getY + getZ*getZ );
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    if (normalizer != 0) {
        x = getX/normalizer;
        y = getY/normalizer;
        z = getZ/normalizer;
    }
    float x2 = pow(x,2);
    float y2 = pow(y,2);
    float z2 = 0;
    float sina = sin(getA);
    float f1cosa = 1-cos(getA);
    PMatrix3D rotationMatrix = new PMatrix3D(
        1+f1cosa*(x2-1),    z*sina+x*y*f1cosa,      -y*sina+x*z*f1cosa,     0,
        -z*sina+x*y*f1cosa, 1+f1cosa*(y2-1),        x*sina+y*z*f1cosa,      0,
        y*sina+x*z*f1cosa,  -x*sina+y*z*f1cosa,     1+f1cosa*(z2-1),        0,
        0,                  0,                      0,                      1
    );
    return rotationMatrix;
}

// Draw
draw() {
mouseRotate();
applyMatrix(currentMatrix);
object.render();
}
```

I thought that using this method would allow me to "stack" cumulative rotations relative to the screen and not relative to the object. But the result seems to always do the rotation relative to the object drawn.

I am not using a camera because I basically only want to rotate the object on itself. I'm actually a bit lost atm on what I should rotate and when to that the newly applied rotations are relative to the user, and the previously applied rotation are conserved.